# How to preserve custom component tag names in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, custom-element, rollup

I'm using Vue's single-file component spec (`*.vue`) for custom components in my application. Together with `rollup` and `rollup-plugin-vue`, I have observed the output in the DOM, for custom components I have written, to be composed of the equivalent html elements.

For example:

*`component-a.vue`*

```
<template>
  <span>Hello World</span>
</template>

<script>
export default { name: 'component-a' };
</script>
```

*`component-b.vue`*

```
<template>
  <component-a></component-a>
</template>

<script>
import ComponentA from './path/to/component-a.vue';

export default { name: 'component-b', components: { ComponentA } };
</script>
```

The above example, if `component-a` is added to the Vue mount component, will render to a the sum of the two component's template *contents* in the DOM, which in this case is simply a `span` element:

```
<span>Hello World<span>
```

Is it possible to achieve a rendered output in the DOM like the snippet below, such that custom elements' templates are represented in the DOM by tags which preserve their tag names?

```
<component-b>
  <component-a>
    <span>Hello World</span>
  </component-a>
</component-b>
```

Comment: There is https://github.com/karol-f/vue-custom-element Haven't used it, though.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. I'm still aiming to find an answer to this that remains native to Vue.

Comment: Have you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `component-a.vue` you should be able to achieve that by including some html code within your `<template>` tag as follow

*component-a.vue:*

```
<template>
    <customelement>
        // Other stuff
    </customelement>
</template>
```

In this way you will be able to call your *component-a* from anywhere in your app, and to render an element named `customelement`.

Ideally you should use this "trick" to render standard HTML5 elements, otherwise you might see some error in your vue app console. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the Vuejs documentation
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats

> It should be noted that this limitation does not apply if you are
> using string templates from one of the following sources:
>
> ```
> String templates (e.g. template: '...')
> Single-file (.vue) components
> <script type="text/x-template">
> ```

If you use Vuejs like the examples above you won't get the result you wanted. So if you render your components in other ways you should get the result you wanted.